# extra site catalyst call on page load

Tags: javascript, adobe-analytics

hi am trying to setup rules in DTM.
Below is my setup - no page load rules

1. Custom Event based rule
2. Direct call rules within custom code of above event based rule.

My expectation is not to fire site catalyst call on custom event based rule but fire only with direct call rules.

Actual result is:
When page is loaded even before firing event based rule- I see a site catalyst call is made 'SATELLITE: Adobe Analytics: tracked page view' I am pretty sure this is coming from scode within DTM but I dont want that to happen rather al my calls should be from direct call rules

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your valuable inputs!!

I could very much suppress the event based and other direct call rules but my major issue was to suppress the initial SC call with page load (happening from DTM library). 
But I could achieve that based on the hostname - I am returning false when my first rule is event based rule.

Answer (score 2):

Add `return false;` to your custom page code within the tool setup. This will prevent the default page view from getting called.

Comment: I tied this but with this my other page load rules are not firing

Comment: @Pankaj-PK Didn't you say that you do not have page load rules?

Comment: So we are using the same property for two sites, so this may work where I don't have page load rules but might break my other sites analytics using page load rules

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this. The easiest is to configure the Adobe Analytics section your event-based rule to not send a request:

```
Adobe Analytics Section - tracking disabled
```

And then call the DC rule via a third-party JS tag in your rule:

```
_satellite.track('MY_RULE_NAME')
```

If for some reason you're firing a page view on event activity (using other rules in the property) you may consider setting a data element when your event-based rule triggers and then in your custom Adobe Analytics configuration abort the analytics call.

```
if(_satellite.getVar('MY_EVENT_BASED_RULE_FIRED')
{
s.abort = true;
}
```

Hope this helps.